# Extract low-frequency coefficients of Fourier transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have applied the Fourier transformation on an image like so:

```
I = imread('img.jpg');
img = fftshift(I);
F = fft2(img);
magnitude = mat2gray(100*log(1+abs(fftshift(F))));    % Magnitude spectrum
phase = mat2gray( (angle(F)) );                       % Phase spectrum
```

Using the energy compaction property of the Discrete Fourier Transform how can I extract a 21x21 matrix of the low-frequency value coefficients of the Fourier transformation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
I = imread('peppers.jpg');
img = fftshift(I);
F = fftshift(fft2(img));

% magnitude = mat2gray(100*log(1+abs(F)));    % Magnitude spectrum
% phase = mat2gray( (angle(F)) );             % Phase spectrum

[M N K] = size(F);

L = 10;

fsub(M,N,K)=0;
fsub(M/2-L:M/2+L,N/2-L:N/2+L,1:K) = F(M/2-L:M/2+L,N/2-L:N/2+L,1:K);


I2 = uint8(real(ifftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(fsub))));

figure
subplot(121)
imshow(I)

subplot(122)
imshow(I2)
```

The panel on the left is the original, the one on the right after selecting only the core frequency components.

[image]